# Kafka Schema Registry - Error starting the schema registry (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication)

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, apache-kafka-security

i'm trying to configure schema registry to work with SSL, i have already zookeeper and kafka brokers working with the same SSL keys. 
but whenever i start the schema-registry i get the following error

```
ERROR Error starting the schema registry   (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication)
 io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.exceptions.SchemaRegistryInitializationException: Error     initializing kafka store while initializing schema registry
    at     io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.init(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:224)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.initSchemaRegistry(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:66)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.configureBaseApplication(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:81)
    at io.confluent.rest.Application.createServer(Application.java:205)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain.main(SchemaRegistryMain.java:42)
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.exceptions.StoreInitializationException: Failed trying to create or validate schema topic configuration
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.createOrVerifySchemaTopic(KafkaStore.java:179)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.init(KafkaStore.java:116)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.init(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:222)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:272)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.createOrVerifySchemaTopic(KafkaStore.java:167)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1521)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:528)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1197)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:1165)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:469)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshakeWrap(SslTransportLayer.java:448)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.doHandshake(SslTransportLayer.java:313)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshake(SslTransportLayer.java:265)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:170)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:547)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:483)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:539)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.run(KafkaAdminClient.java:1152)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1709)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:318)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:970)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:967)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1459)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.runDelegatedTasks(SslTransportLayer.java:402)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshakeUnwrap(SslTransportLayer.java:484)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.doHandshake(SslTransportLayer.java:340)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:281)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1626)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
    ... 22 more
```

`schema-registry.properties` configuration :

```
listeners=https://localhost:8081
kafkastore.connection.url=localhost:2181
kafkastore.bootstrap.servers=SSL://localhost:9092
kafkastore.topic=_schemas
kafkastore.topic.replication.factor=1
kafkastore.security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/.kafka_ssl/kafka.server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=password
ssl.keystore.location=/.kafka_ssl/kafka.server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=password
ssl.key.password=password
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
inter.instance.protocol=https
```

can someone advise ?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that after enabling SSL, the following environment variables are exported:

```
export SCHEMA_REGISTRY_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/var/private/ssl/clientkeystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/var/private/ssl/clienttruststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=mypass-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=mypass"
export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/var/private/ssl/clientkeystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/var/private/ssl/clienttruststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=mypass-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=mypass"
```

---

For more details, refer to Confluent's Documentation [Additional Configurations for HTTPS](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/security/index.html#additional-configurations-for-https)

Answer (score 1):

you need add ssl connection properties to the schema registry as well

```
ssl.truststore.location=/.kafka_ssl/kafka.server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=password
ssl.keystore.location=/.kafka_ssl/kafka.server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=password
ssl.key.password=password
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=

schema.registry.ssl.truststore.location=/.kafka_ssl/kafka.server.truststore.jks
schema.registry.ssl.truststore.password=password
schema.registry.ssl.keystore.location=/.kafka_ssl/kafka.server.keystore.jks
schema.registry.ssl.keystore.password=password
schema.registry.ssl.key.password=password
```

it worked for me